# How to redirect to another URL if visitor is anonymous when clicking a menu?

Tags: routes

I used the following code to redirect anonymous visitor to a login page:

```
<?php
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    print "<a href='http://www.sourcecodester.com/submit'>Submit now...</a>";
  }
  else {
    print "<a href='http://www.sourcecodester.com/user?destination=submit'>Submit now...</a>";
  }
?>
```

But I can do this only in a block. What I want is put a Submit menu in the main menu and if anonymous visitor click the link he/she will be redirect to:

http://www.sourcecodester.com/user?destination=submit

after he/she login, he/she will be redirect again to the submit page as defined in the URL as "destination=submit".

Is this possible in main menu?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Menu per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module:

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items1 based on user
>   roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both
>   modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset
>   that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears
>   in the node edit form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) if you want ... but sometimes large modules are overkill for simple things. Using a custom module you can essentially intercept the page click/load with your own hook_menu() or hook_menu_alter() implementation:

```
// If this is just a simple drupal Page node or Article node for instance
// you would want to use "function mymodule_menu_alter($items) { ..." here.
//
// If this is a page you made programatically, you would do as below ...
function mymodule_menu() {
  // You have some generic "submit" page that you want the user
  // logged in 1st before they visit it. That is to say there
  // is a requirement that they be logged in.
  $items['submit']=array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_submitview',
     // We want to provide a custom check to be visitor is
     // logged in 1st.
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_submit_requires_login_callback',
  );
  return $items;
}

// Simple page output for example.
function mymodule_submitview() {
  return user_is_anonymous() ? 'I am anonymous.' : 'I am logged in.';
}

// Our custom 'access callback' function to perform or logic check.
function mymodule_submit_requires_login_callback() {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    // send the user to the login form and make that form redirect
    // submission to our custom submit page.
    drupal_goto("user/login?destination=submit");
    // implicit exit; here.
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules you can get this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try this:

```
function YOURMODULENAME__form_alter() {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block') {
    $form['#action'] = 'node?destination=YOURDESTINATION';
  }
}
```